stability of operators under perturbation
Let $\rho$ be a positive semi-definite matrix with trace one (a density matrix). Assume $H$ is a self-adjoint operator, bounded from below, with a spectrum consisting of isolated eigenvalues $E_n (E_0 < E_1 < ...)$ with finite multiplicities $d(n)$, and $Tr[exp(- \beta H)] < \infty$ for all positive $\beta$. Furthermore, let $\lambda$ be a small positive constant, and $V$ a relatively bounded self-adjoint operator with respect to H, i.e., there exist constants $a, b > 0$ such that
$$  ||V \psi || \leq a ||H \psi || + b ||\psi||$$ for all $\psi \in D(H) \subseteq D(V)$.
We say that $\rho$ is stable with respect to $H$ if, for every $H$-bounded self-adjoint operator $V$, and for every bounded self-adjoint operator $O$, it holds
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{\lambda\to 0}\sup_{t\geq 0} \left(Tr\left[O  e^{-i t (H+\lambda V)} \rho e^{i t (H+\lambda V)} \right] - Tr\left[O \rho\right]\right)
    = 0\, .
\end{equation}
Suppose I perturb one eigenvalue of the operator H, say $E_m$, and modify it to $E_m':= \frac{p}{q} E_n$, where $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $H'$ denote the new operator, which has the same eigenvalues as $H$, except that $E_m$ is replaced by $E'_m$. My question is: If I assume that $\rho$ is stable with respect to $H$, is it stable with respect to $H'$ as well? My intuition suggests yes since only one eigenvalue is being changed, but I'm unsure how to formally prove it. Note that all the operators are defined in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and not necessarily commute with each other.
